# What's the average number of transistor switches needed to do an N-bit x N-bit multiply?

Tags: algorithms, computer-architecture, logic, arithmetic, boolean-algebra

I want to know how switch-efficient a multiplier can be. If I need to do many $N$-bit by $N$-bit multiplies, and each bit is determined by flipping a coin, what's the average number of transistor switches that will be required per multiply, in terms of $N$?

Comment: Is a "switch" just a transistor? Or is it the act of a transistor output "changing state"? Because the latter is something that only makes sense to me when the transistor is part of a memory circuit, and a multiplier can be implemented without memory. Next: What multiplication algorithm is being used?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm) has a thorough page on the bit complexity of integer multiplication. I am not aware of any work which tries to take advantage of many different multiplications being done at once.

Comment: A 'switch' is the transistor changing state. I think all transistors have this property, not just memory-- if you're e.g. using a transistor to compute a NOT, if the transistor is in a 1 state and you give it a 1 as input, it will have to switch to the 0 (NOT 1) state.

Comment: There is an unfortunate ambiguity in the meaning of *switch* here. Neither *toggle* nor *flip*, *inversion*, *(signal) edge*, or *(state) change* seem any better. *Transition* is used for *change in stored state* more often than for *signal state change*, e.g, change in the state of an automaton. (The other meaning being *device steered between *passing/conducting* and *blocking/isolating* - electrical charges, photons, molecules - you name it.)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to incorporate relevant information into your post, including defining what you mean by "switch", so it is self-contained and reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time, and so people don't have to read the comments to understand what you're asking.  Then you can flag the comments as 'no longer needed' once all of that information has been incorporated into the question.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't edited my question, but in case others are here: this thesis addresses the question I was intending (https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/52104064.pdf), finding e.g. 1189 average transitions required for a certain architecture for a 16-bit by 16-bit multiply that's completely random bits.
\